# Unexpected behavior of recursive_directory_iterator on windows10

Tags: c++, windows, boost-filesystem

I have a function that experiences a hang issue on Windows 10 but runs smoothly on Linux. The problematic line of code seems to be `bfs::recursive_directory_iterator it(dirPath)`. After this point, no further code execution occurs.

However, when I substitute `boost::filesystem` with `std::filesystem`, everything works as expected. Can anyone shed light on why this behavior is occurring?

I am using Boost version 1.82.

Here's the function in question:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

void listFilesRecursive(const bfs::path &dirPath, std::vector<std::string> &filePaths)
{
    // Convert dirPath to a string and print it
    std::string dirPathStr = dirPath.string();
    std::cout << "Directory path: " << dirPathStr << std::endl;

    // Check if the directory exists and is a directory
    if (!bfs::exists(dirPath) || !bfs::is_directory(dirPath))
    {
        std::cout << "dirPath not exist" << dirPath << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for (bfs::recursive_directory_iterator it(dirPath), end; it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (bfs::is_regular_file(*it))
        {
            std::cout << "filepath=" << it->path().string() << std::endl;
            filePaths.push_back(it->path().string());
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::string dirPathStr = "/path/to/your/directory";   
    std::vector<std::string> filePaths;
    listFilesRecursive(dirPath, filePaths);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging by adding more print statements? Maybe it causes recursion when it encounters `.` or `..`?

Comment: "However, when I substitute boost::filesystem with std::filesystem, everything works as expected." - There's your solution then 

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: std::filesystem is  provided by c++17 and on my device linaro tool chain version doesn't support c++17 .  I can use only c++14 :(

Comment: As code is hanging so print statement is not captured and no exception thrown by boost.

Comment: Please confirm that you have `using namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;`, `bfs` not being a standard name space.

Comment: Also please [edit] and show a [mre], especially the code that calls `listFilesRecursive`.

Comment: namespace bfs = boost::filesystem; is not a standard C++ namespace. It's a common practice to create an alias for a long or frequently used namespace to make the code more concise

Comment: Use Process Monitor to see what files/directories it is accessing while it's "hanging", maybe that gives you a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if recursive path is too deep then usually boost hangs and you won't be able get any error or exception from boost .I would suggest use conditional compilation to address this issue.

```
#ifdef _WIN64 // Check if compiling on Windows (64-bit)
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#else // Not compiling on Windows (64-bit), assume Linux
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;
#endif // _WIN64
```

in this way on windows you can compile and executing the code using std::filesystem and on linux using boost::filesystem

Comment: yes you are right as while printing I didn't see any value of dirPath variable and it was hanging and after sometime I was able to see the terminal . Using boost same code works fine on linux but no luck on windows.